# Debugging bash functions

Tags: bash, shell

So here I have a simple function that I wish to debug.  However, I am unable to debug the desired function even with `set -o functrace` enabled.   Before resorting to asking this question, I had managed to find a possible solution that did not produce the desired results, which is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415235/bash-debug-option-and-functions).

How can I get bash debug my functions?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
hello() {
    echo "Hello world"
}
```

output:

```
user@mac11:53:29~/desktop bash -x debug.sh 
+ echo 'Hello World'
Hello World
user@mac11:54:55~/desktop
```

Comment: In the example code, function `hello` is never called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

but that answer in the link does seem to work ........

```
  Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat zhello.sh
  set -x ;
  set -o functrace

  hello()
  {
   name=$1;
   echo "Hello , how are you $name";
 }

 hello "itin" ;
```

output is :

```
 Kaizen ~/so_test $ ./zhello.sh
  + ./zhello.sh                     --  script was run 
 ++ set -o functrace
 ++ hello itin                      -- function was invoked
 ++ name=itin                       -- variable assigned within the function hello 
 ++ echo 'Hello , how are you itin'
 Hello , how are you itin           -- printed the output from the function ...
```

I am a bit curious , is there something specific you looking for ?

Comment: I forgot to call it.  Sorry, I'm new to the whole bash scripting thing.

Comment: @BrandonD , no problem .... all this helps learn !!

Answer (score 2):

The function `hello()` was not called at the end of script.  User error.